# Why timeout is needed for UDP send when UDP is connectionless?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, timeout

So I see that there are methods provided to specify timeout value while sending data over UDP packets (at least saw that in C#). I was wondering what's the use of that as I thought UDP is a connectionless protocol and all the sender socket has to do is just send the packet without worrying about the packet being actually received. It makes sense to have a timeout on receive, but I am not sure why would you need a timeout on send. Can someone please explain?

That brings up another question, is UDP send blocking? (I would say not). If yes, what things does it get "blocked" on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A timeout is not _needed_ it is optional, typically one will not use it.

Answer (score 6):

Both questions have the same answer. `send()` just copies the datagram to the socket send buffer, which is then sent to the network by the OS in the background. If the buffer is full, it blocks. For UDP the buffer can fill up if you are sending datagrams faster than the OS can write them to the network.

Sockets can be either blocking (default) or non-blocking, whether they are TCP or UDP.

Comment: Thanks. So if the buffer is full & the waiting time exceeds the given timeout value then the call returns/throws an exception?

Comment: I don't see what else it could possibly mean.